# About limited finite sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $n \in \Bbb N$ be a positive integer and let $a_1,...,a_n \in \Bbb C$.
Let $D \subset \Bbb C$ be a compact subset of $\Bbb C$ and let $M \in \Bbb R_+$

> I would like to know if there exist $z_1,...,z_n \in D$ such that $$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n z_ja_j\right|>M.$$
>   Thanks

Comment: It depends on $M, a_i$ and $D$.

Comment: What if $D=\{0\}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is false.

As $D$ is compact, it is also limited, let's say a bound for $|z|$ for any $z\in D$ is $K$. Consider also $L:=\max_i(|a_i|)$. So we have that for any $z_1,z_2,\dots ,z_n\in D$:

$$|\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_ia_i|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}|z_ia_i|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}KL=nKL$$

So we have that such statement is not valid for any $M>nKL$.

Answer (score 1):

Take your compact subspace to be the unit disc. Then $$\left|\sum a_iz_i\right|\leq \sum \left|a_i\right|\leq n\max_i{\left|a_i\right|}$$ by Cauchy Schwartz. So if $a_k$ is the largest element in the sequence by absolute value, then setting. $M=n|a_k|+1$ gives a counter example.